# Reading input in C

Tags: c

I have to read input from the user. I do not know how many lines or how many character per line the user will input, so I can't use an array. If the user inputs an empty line, the input is complete.

My question is, how to do this without the use of arrays. I tried using this code, but it crashes on running.

```
char *line = "";
gets(line);
```

Why does this not work? And how can I read the input without the use of arrays?

TIA

Comment: Read about string literal in C.. There are thousands of question in stackoverflow itself. Probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string) will help you.

Comment: this is a string literal (an empty one), not an array of characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That doesn't work because `line` points at only enough memory to store an empty string, and that memory is typically non-modifiable since string literals cannot be changed at run-time.

You need an actual buffer, like so:

```
char line[128];
```

Note that `gets()` is best avoided, it won't protect against buffer overrun and thus is always going to be dangerous.

Use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead:

```
if( fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL)
{
  printf("got some input!\n");
}
```

You say for some reason that you want to do this "without arrays", which is kind of ... hard, since any "buffer" is pretty much an array in C. If you want to avoid using the  `[]` syntax, you need to dynamically allocate the memory instead using `malloc()`.

Then you can't use `sizeof` like above, it will evaluate to the size of the pointer. Now you need:

```
const size_t buffer_size = 128;
char *line;

if((line = malloc(buffer_size)) != NULL)
{
    if(fgets(line, buffer_size, stdin) != NULL)
    {
       /* use the data we just read in */
    }
    free(line);  /* discard the buffer so we don't leak memory. */
}
```

Comment: but this will read only 1 line. and the OP says that the user culd enter many lines. you have to use while instead of if

Comment: good point about `gets()`.. A bad mistake which so many beginners commit

Comment: To be precise, attempting to modify a string literal results in Undefined Behavior.